# C# Main Thread completes same action faster than any other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was perfomancing some Inter-Process (Inter-Application) communication code in C#.
And noticed if I run test on Main thread, test completes between 20~30% faster.
Regardless if action is called as function/method or we use SynchronizationContext of Main thread and Post action.
So I've started examining the behaviour of main thread and noticed that main thread never sleeps.
I gather main thread is responsible for UI responsiveness and needs to run message pump (maybe the answer is message pump, and OS scheduler gives more time slices to such threads?). I am looking for better understanding the reasoning behind this.

I've made some test code, run it more than dosen times, and each time test shows main thread start executing process after other thread, and that main thread manages to complete work faster from other thread. Here is the code of the test .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CSMainThread
{
  static class MainThreadTest
  {
    static ManualResetEvent eventRace = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static object SyncObject = new object();
    static int prizeStart = 0;
    static int prizeEnd = 0;

    static long[] slices = new long[2];
    static int[] countsStart = new int[2];
    static int[] countsEnd = new int[2];

    static ManualResetEvent[] eventPrepStart = new ManualResetEvent[2] { new ManualResetEvent(false), new ManualResetEvent(false) };
    
    static Thread tOther;
    static Thread tSync;

    public static void Test()
    {
      DateTime tt = DateTime.Now;
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
        eventRace.Reset();
        prizeStart = 1;
        prizeEnd = 1;
        tOther  = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        tSync = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadProcSync));        
        // start starter thread, before main thread
        tSync.Start(); 
        // start other thread
        tOther.Start(1);
        // go with main thread
        ThreadProc(0);
        // wait other thread end
        tOther.Join();        
      }
      Debug.Print("Total test time {0} ms", (DateTime.Now - tt).TotalMilliseconds);
      Debug.Print(new string('-', 60));
      Debug.Print("Thread  | Start |   End | Slices");
      Debug.Print(new string('-', 60));
      Debug.Print(" Main   | {0,5} | {1,5} | {2}", countsStart[0], countsEnd[0], slices[0]);
      Debug.Print(" Other  | {0,5} | {1,5} | {2}", countsStart[1], countsEnd[1], slices[1]);
      Debug.Print(new string('-', 60));
    }

    static void ThreadProcSync(object threadData)
    {
      // wait both threads start
      while (!eventPrepStart[0].WaitOne(0) || !eventPrepStart[1].WaitOne(0))
        Thread.Yield();
  
      // NOTE criteria : Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin is never satisfied !!!
      //                 MainThread never enters wait state, and this is Dead Locking sync thread !!!
      //
      // ensure wait is on both threads
      //while (!(Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin && tOther.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
      //  Thread.Yield();      
      while (!(tOther.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
        Thread.Yield();      

      // run the race
      eventRace.Set();      
    }

    static void ThreadProc(object threadData)
    {
      double x = 0;
      int i;
      DateTime tt;
      int index = (Int32)threadData;
      eventPrepStart[index].Set();
      eventRace.WaitOne();

      // make sure no wait happens out of order
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();
      
      lock (SyncObject)
      {
        tt = DateTime.Now;
        // the one that gets here first takes the prize
        countsStart[index] += prizeStart;
        prizeStart = 0;        
      }      
      for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      {
        x += Math.Cos(i) * Math.Sin(i);
      }
      lock (SyncObject)
      {
        slices[index] += (DateTime.Now - tt).Ticks;
        // the one that gets here first takes the prize
        countsEnd[index] += prizeEnd;
        prizeEnd = 0;
      }
      
      // get ready for next run
      eventPrepStart[index].Reset();
      
    }

  }
}
```

maybe it requires more work on it (HighPerfomanceCounters...), but in general gives us some picture

And here is the result I get, in most cases other thread runs first and gets Start Prize, but in ~50% of times Main thread catches up Other thread for End prize and wins the race.

```
Total test time 12202.698 ms
------------------------------------------------------------
Thread  | Start |   End | Slices
------------------------------------------------------------
Main   |     3 |    62 | 94465397
Other  |    97 |    38 | 99685701
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone has any insight what is really happening, and why Main thread completes more faster?

Edit: took some high performance counter profiler only for FOR(Cos*Sin), and it gave back same thing.

```
Total test time 11804.6752 ms
------------------------------------------------------------
Thread  | Start |   End | Slices
------------------------------------------------------------
 Main   |     2 |    54 | 91425226
 Other  |    98 |    46 | 98455625
------------------------------------------------------------
HPC[1001]::ShowStatistic() called from : [JITTrack,JITOpt] CSMainThread.MainThreadTest::Test()
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ meter : sumtime  / cnt ~ average  | times * time.min ~ time.max : max-min  ( max-avrg , avrg-min ) over time improving  │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Main  : 8.536089 / 100 ~ 0.085361 |     3 * 0.073004 ~ 0.219276 : 0.146273 ( 0.133915 , 0.012357 ) ▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫ │
│ Other : 9.560208 / 100 ~ 0.095602 |     2 * 0.072965 ~ 0.173809 : 0.100844 ( 0.078207 , 0.022637 ) ▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫ │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: You have made a perfect "*something is faster than something else*" benchmark. As for what exactly you are trying to benchmark, *the jury is out*. What are you trying to prove here? What is the workload?, as its really hard to tell the motivation

Comment: I am trying to understand mechanics behind why code is executed faster on Main thread. Cause in code I was profiling the speed I got is ~33% faster on Main thread which is not small, could it be used as technique for boosting other applications execution? At this point it looks like the race toook place in dark cave, and winner is always the Main thread. I would like to see the race, how did Main thread overtook the Other thread and what gave him this advantage.

Comment: If you want to pick up your pencil from your desk, what is faster? Do it by yourself (MainThread) or call your mother to do it for you (OtherThread)? There is some overhead to get a new thread up and running and that is what you have measured here

Comment: Well if you look closely both calculations start on eventRace.Set() and the Other thread starts the race first (not second as you assumed). So my mother and me are both on start line ready to go both in same time, and she seems to have better reflexes and starts running first.

Answer (score 2):

Never seen something like this:

Please try the following:

- Change the starting order of the threads, I think this might affect
  the resources affected to each one.
- Disable every service you can from the computer that is running the
  program.

I don't think this has something to do with the main thread/"normal thread" but with the way your SO is handling the resources attribution and concurrence for each thread (in this case .

Comment: Order can't be changed! (check the code), both threads are in eventRace.WaitOne(); and waiting for signal to start the Race (while Main thread is actually in running state, probably because of UI message pumping, the other thread is in Wait state). This is not woodoo that some service... this repeatable behavior that is observed for the fact. I am only looking for the reason why it is happening. Although didn't try to run same on server OS, might get difference results. That is for TODO list. but thanks for trying, I think that this has to do something with OS process scheduler (time slices).

Answer (score 1):

1. I refactored your code a bit to make the sync between referee and threads a bit simpler.
2. I didn't observe what you did, unfortunately. What I actually get is more-or-less even distribution. I did only a handful of test, though. Also, I didn't turn off anything on my computer that might skew results, so my Spotify was on and e-mail were coming in. Compare results at the bottom of this post

**my code**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace CSMainThread
{
    static class MainThreadTest
    {
        static object SyncObject = new object();
        static int prizeStart = 0;
        static int prizeEnd = 0;

        static long[] slices = new long[2];
        static int[] countsStart = new int[2];
        static int[] countsEnd = new int[2];

        public static void Main()
        {
            using var eventRace = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            DateTime tt = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Debug.Print($"Run #{i}");
                eventRace.Reset();
                using var competitors = new CountdownEvent(2);
                prizeStart = 1;
                prizeEnd = 1;
                // start starter thread, before main thread
                // start other thread
                var tOther = new Thread(ThreadProc);
                var tSync = new Thread(RefereeThread);
                tSync.Start((sync: eventRace, referee: competitors));
                tOther.Start((index: 1, sync: eventRace, referee: competitors));
                // go with main thread
                ThreadProc((index: 0, sync: eventRace, referee: competitors));
                // wait other thread end
                tOther.Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total test time {0} ms", (DateTime.Now - tt).TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));
            Console.WriteLine("Thread  | Start |   End | Slices");
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));
            Console.WriteLine(" Main   | {0,5} | {1,5} | {2}", countsStart[0], countsEnd[0], slices[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(" Other  | {0,5} | {1,5} | {2}", countsStart[1], countsEnd[1], slices[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));
        }

        static void RefereeThread(object data)
        {
            var (sync, referee) = ((
                ManualResetEvent sync,
                CountdownEvent referee))data;

            // Wait for all the threads we're checking to get to their `referee.Signal`.
            referee.Wait();
            // Give threads some time to fall into wait procedure.
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            // start the race
            sync.Set();
        }

        static void ThreadProc(object data)
        {
            var (index, sync, referee) = ((
                int index,
                ManualResetEvent sync,
                CountdownEvent referee))data;
            double x = 0;
            int i;
            DateTime tt;

            // make sure no wait happens out of order
            referee.Signal();
            sync.WaitOne();

            lock (SyncObject)
            {
                tt = DateTime.Now;
                // the one that gets here first takes the prize
                countsStart[index] += prizeStart;
                prizeStart = 0;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                x += Math.Cos(i) * Math.Sin(i);
            }
            lock (SyncObject)
            {
                slices[index] += (DateTime.Now - tt).Ticks;
                // the one that gets here first takes the prize
                countsEnd[index] += prizeEnd;
                prizeEnd = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**results**

[image]